# Fix cannot GET /url react router

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const path = require('path');

const app = express()

app.use(express())
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')))

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    console.log('server is up')
})

app.get('/data', (req, res)=>{
    res.send({name: 'name', age: 'age' })
})

app.listen(5000)
```

I am getting cannot Get /URL. I want to run build index.html file with express. React Router is not working. Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You should be routing all the request to the index.html assuming its a SPA(Single Page Application)

like this:

```js
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('index.html', {root: path.join(__dirname, '../../client/build/')});
});
```

Comment: It is not a single page application.